# Angular redirect to dist

Tags: angular, apache

Is there a solution to automatically redirect to Angular `dist` folder if we first try to acess to the root project ? (Instead of display the following) :
[image]

I tried with .htaccess but without success, I have a 404 error :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dist/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dist/$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/opencaptureforinvoices\/dist\/
RewriteRule ^ /opencaptureforinvoices/dist/ [R=302,L]
# or remove R=302 if you need internal redirect
```